# Flex / mx spark : create a numpad layout (table style)

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Is there a way to create an interface and positionnate/scale elements with percentages values only? I'm new with Flex and I can't find a way to achieve this.

I have been able to create a numpad with a basic layout but I must use absolute positions (x & y) :

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="400" height="500">
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="0" y="0" width="25%" height="20%" label="NUM LOCK"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="0" width="25%" height="20%" label="/"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="0" width="25%" height="20%" label="*"/>
    <s:Button x="300" y="0" width="25%" height="20%" label="-"/>

    <s:Button x="0" y="100" width="25%" height="20%" label="7"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="100" width="25%" height="20%" label="8"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="100" width="25%" height="20%" label="9"/>
    <s:Button x="300" y="100" width="25%" height="40%" label="+"/>

    <s:Button x="0" y="200" width="25%" height="20%" label="4"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="200" width="25%" height="20%" label="5"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="200" width="25%" height="20%" label="6"/>

    <s:Button x="0" y="300" width="25%" height="20%" label="1"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="300" width="25%" height="20%" label="2"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="300" width="25%" height="20%" label="3"/>
    <s:Button x="300" y="300" width="25%" height="40%" label="ENTER"/>

    <s:Button x="0" y="400" width="50%" height="20%" label="0"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="400" width="25%" height="20%" label="."/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Result :

[image]

The problem is when I scale the numpad all goes wrong - since I am stuck with absolute values (x=100 y=200). I can't use percentages (x=25% y=40% or x="{this.width*1/4}" y="{this.height*2/5}")

[image]
[image]

Aslo, I need to use percentages because there is many numpad configurations (some numpad has the enter button only at bottom right, others has a "0" button that takes only 1 space at the bottom left). Working with absolute values is something I want to avoid if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use grid layout with columnspan and rowspan(on grid item) for multiple row/column, set the children widths & height to 100%. set the gap to 0 on the parent.

More on it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Grid.html)

```
<mx:Grid id="myGrid" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:GridRow>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="NL" width="100%" height="100%" >
                </mx:Button>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="/" width="100%" height="100%" >
                </mx:Button>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="*" width="100%" height="100%" >
                </mx:Button>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="-" width="100%" height="100%" >
                </mx:Button>
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow id="row1">
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="7"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="8"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="9"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem rowSpan="2">
                <mx:Button label="+"  width="100%" height="100%"  />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow id="row2">
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="4"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="5"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="6"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow id="row4">
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="1"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="2"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="3"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem rowSpan="2">
                <mx:Button label="ENTR"  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow id="row5">
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="2">
                <mx:Button label="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="."  width="100%" height="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
```